# React and ag-grid - how do you update the `getRowClass` function?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Here's a StackBlitz that demonstrates the issue/question: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s9l2kj

(this is essentially a modified version of the [Example Row Class Rules](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#example-row-class-rules) code from the ag-grid website)

I have a `getRowClass` function that needs to be updated when a property passed to my component changes. In the provided code example, this is passed to the `Grid` component (here's a cut-down version):

```
const Grid = (props) => {
  const getRowClass = (params) => {
    var numSickDays = params.data.sickDays;

    if (numSickDays > props.minDays && numSickDays <= props.maxDays) {
      return 'sick-days-warning';
    };

    return '';
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={data}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        getRowClass={getRowClass}
      />

      <label>Show warning when: {props.minDays} &lt; sick days &lt;= {props.maxDays}</label>
    </>
  );
}
```

In the StackBlitz example, updating the value in the `Min days` textbox correctly causes the label to re-render, showing that the new property is correctly being passed to the grid.

#### Question

Why doesn't the `getRowClass` function get updated? It looks to me like the `AgGridReact` is caching the first value for `getRowClass` that gets passed to it, rather than updating it when a new `getRowClass` function is getting created - so that feels like a bug... however, I may be misunderstanding how I should be updating the `getRowClass` function.

Comment: your getRowClass is basically instantiated only once along with gridOptions. not su re if there is a way to update getRowClass. - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1695

Comment: Thanks @PratikBhat for the reply - I can't find a way to update the `getRowClass` function using the API either unfortunately... the only work around I can find is to rebuild the whole grid :-|

Answer (score 0):

Please try by defining the getRowClass function inside the gridOptions field and assign this to Ag-grid.

```
const gridOptions = {
    // all rows assigned CSS class 'my-green-class'
    rowClass: 'my-green-class',

    getRowClass = (params) => {
    if (params.data.sickDays > 8) return 'sick-days-breach';

    var numSickDays = params.data.sickDays;
    if (numSickDays > props.minDays && numSickDays <= props.maxDays) {
      return 'sick-days-warning';
    };

    return '';
  };
}

<AgGridReact
        rowData={data}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        getRowClass={getRowClass}
        gridOptions = {gridOptions}
       />
```